# Does Media Player Framework need audio sessions to be managed?

Tags: ios, media-player, core-audio, avaudiosession, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'd like to include a simple media player in my iOS 7+ app, and I've found some posts dealing with `Media Player Framework` and the `MPMusicPlayerController`, and I think that can meet my needs. However, I couldn't find the related documentation in Apple's docs, and instead I found that there are several frameworks related to managing audio in iOS apps.

I've taken a look into the `Core Audio Overview` and the "Sound" section in `iOS Human Interface Guidelines`, and I need to clarify if it is also needed to manage audio sessions when using `Media Player Framework`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithMoviesandiPodMusic/WorkingwithMoviesandiPodMusic.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH7-SW5):

> If your app is using a movie player only, or a music player only—and you are not playing your own sounds—then you should not configure an audio session.